# Filter/Highlight areas on a map by critera

Tags: maps, gis

I'm looking for a tool to filter/highlight areas on map by criteria. As an example I'd like to get all areas in a town which are at least 100m away from a highway and closer than 2km to a train station.

Does anyone know a tool or coding libraries I can use?

Comment: What format is your data in? What output format do you want? What budget?